# Fetch all the contact and all the keys using new Contact Framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, contacts

I want to fetch all the contacts without filter and all the information of their keys.

```
func unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(_ predicate: NSPredicate,
                          keysToFetch keys: [CNKeyDescriptor]) throws -> [CNContact]
```

I am using above method to fetch contact.

is i have to specify all the keys?
is their is any shortcut to fetch all the keys information without specifying all of them?

Answer (score 0):

No. You will have to specify all the required keys by yourself. Please have a look at apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html)
**EDIT:**Please try this method:

```
-(void)getAllContacts
{
    //keys with fetching properties
    NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
    NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
  //to fetch all contacts
    NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];

    //to fetch contacts with matching name
//    NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsMatchingName:@"vishal"];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
    } else {
        for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {
            // copy data to my custom Contacts class.
            Contact *newContact = [[Contact alloc] init];
            newContact.firstName = contact.givenName;
            newContact.lastName = contact.familyName;
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];
            newContact.image = image;
            for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers) {
                NSString *phone = [label.value stringValue];
                if ([phone length] > 0) {
                    [newContact.phones addObject:phone];
                }
            }
            [contacts addObject:newContact];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what about predicate ..is i must have to specify it? coz i want all the contacts.

Comment: You can use predicate if you want to filter the data. Like                              let contacts = try store.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName("XYZ"), keysToFetch:[CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey])    This will return contacts matching with Name "XYZ" and keys will be CNContactGivenNameKey and CNContactFamilyNameKey.